# How do I show that the average energy scales with the number of particles $N$?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, entropy

I am taking a statistical mechanics class and so far I am finding it quite challenging.

I am trying to show that $\frac{\langle{}\sqrt{\Delta{}E^2}\rangle{}}{\langle{}E\rangle{}} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$

I have first used the fact that the heat capacity at constant volume $C_V$ is an extensive property and thus scales with particle number $N$.

Given that $\langle\Delta{E^2}\rangle=C_Vk_bT^2$, we know that $\langle\Delta{E^2}\rangle$ must scale with $N$ and hence $\langle\sqrt{\Delta{E^2}}\rangle$ must scale with $\sqrt{N}$.

I am then trying to show that $\langle{}E\rangle$ scales with $N$ so that $\frac{\langle{}\sqrt{\Delta{}E^2}\rangle{}}{\langle{}E\rangle{}} \sim \frac{\sqrt{N}}{N}\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$.

Why does $\langle{}E\rangle$ scale with $N$ and how do you show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not easy to prove this mathematically in a general system in thermal equilibrium, we can easily prove it in non-interacting systems, which encompasses a wide range of problems in statistical mechanics.

In the canonical ensemble,
$$E=-\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \ln Q$$
where $\beta^{-1}=K_B T$ and $Q$ is the partition function:
$$Q_N= \int d^{3N}p \,d^{3N}q\, e^{-\beta H}$$
Obviously, when the system is non-interactingt, the Hamiltonian can simply be written as $H=\sum_i^N H_i$, where $H_i$ is the Hamiltonian of the $i^{th}$ single component in the system. therefore,
$$Q_N=(Q_1)^N$$
$Q_1$ is the Hamiltonian of a single component. Substituting into the first equation we get
$$E=-N \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \ln Q_1 = N E_1$$
This justifies $E\sim N$.

Examples of non-interactive systems:

1. Ideal gas: $H=\sum_i \frac{p_i^2}{2m}$
2. Resonator: $H=\sum_i \frac{p_i^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}k x_i^2$
3. Paramagnetic system: $H=- \sum_i \vec{\mu}_i . \vec{B}$
4. Relativistic gas: $H=\sum_i p_i c$
   ...

Hope this helps.